# Не работает изменение сообщения в pyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, edit

```
bot.edit_message_text(text="test", chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)
```

Не работает программа. Цель: изменить сообщение на "test". Код выше. Внутри этой функции вывод текста работает, так что это не опечатка в функции. Не работает изменение. Я даже дал боту ВСЕ права, но он все равно не работает. Выдает следующую ошибку:

`A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:`
`[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message can\'t be edited"}']`

Comment: Бот не может и свои сообщения менять?

Comment: @gil9red Может.

Comment: предоставьте больше деталей о редактируемом сообщении, мб нужно `message.message_id - 1`?

Answer (score -1):

Надо убрать text=.
То есть надо писать `bot.edit_message_text("test", chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)`.

Так же бот не может редактировать сообщения от пользователя, если он не является админом группы.